# SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' in Next.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

When I render the code below I get this error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
>
> (project
> path)/node_modules/react-syntax-highlighter/dist/esm/styles/prism/index.js

It initially works as intended until I refresh the page.

```
import { Prism as SyntaxHighlighter } from "react-syntax-highlighter";
import { oneLight } from "react-syntax-highlighter/dist/esm/styles/prism";

const codeString = '(num) => num + 1';

const Code = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <SyntaxHighlighter language="javascript" style={oneLight}>
        {codeString}
      </SyntaxHighlighter>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Code;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solution for `Unexpected token 'export'` in Next.js when using `react-syntax-highlighter`

Use this import path:

```
react-syntax-highlighter/dist/cjs/...
```

instead of:

```
react-syntax-highlighter/dist/esm/...
```